# node-forge import in angular 2 service

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am trying to use Forge (https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge) in my Angular 2 project.

I ran the following command :`npm install node-forge`
This command created the node-forge directory in my application (in the node-modules directory).

I added the node-forge reference in my package.json file: `"node-forge": "0.6.39"` (dependencies section).

Now, i want to import the node-forge dependency in my angular 2 service (typescript file) with the following code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Forge } from 'node-forge';

@Injectable()
export class HashPasswordService {
  constructor() {}
  buildHash(input: string) {
    var hmac = forge.hmac.create();
    hmac.start('sha512', input);
    hmac.update(input);
    return hmac.digest().toHex();
  }
}
```

but the import does not work : `import { Forge } from 'node-forge';` and i have the following errors in the console (ng serve command):

```
hash-password.service.ts (2, 23): Cannot find module 'node-forge'.
hash-password.service.ts (11, 16): Cannot find name 'forge'.
```

So, someone know how i can import this node-forge dependency (use a npm package)? Do I miss a step in my process ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3):

Just `import * as forge from 'node-forge'`, that's it.

Answer (score 2):

You need the typescript definitions as well as the npm package..

I'm not sure if this package has a `DefinitelyTyped` package so you can try

```
npm install typings -g
typings install node-forge
```

If this doesn't work try:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

declare var Forge: any;

@Injectable()
export class HashPasswordService {
  private forge: any;

  constructor() {
     this.forge = new Forge();
  }

  buildHash(input: string) {
    var hmac = forge.hmac.create();
    hmac.start('sha512', input);
    hmac.update(input);
    return hmac.digest().toHex();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install these two packages

```
npm install node-forge
npm install @types/node-forge
```

and `import * as forge from 'node-forge'`, that's all...You are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

This is because 'node-forge' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export.

The following works for me:

```
import pkg from 'node-forge';
const {pkcs5, cipher, util} = pkg;
```